# publish android gradle project to local maven repo

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I created android studio project and now i want to publish it to local maven repo with gradle, so that it can be used as dependency to other projects.

searched a lot but can't find solution.

tried :

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish' //never succed
```